# False positives when checking if ellipses overlap in Python using Shapely

Tags: python, overlap, shapely

I am trying to find if 2 ellipses overlap. I am testing with 200 ellipses that should not overlap. Using shapely it gives sometimes random false positives and I don't know why. Here is the code

```
def ellipse_polyline(ellipses, n=100):
    t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n)
    st = np.sin(t)
    ct = np.cos(t)
    result = []
    for x0, y0, a, b, angle in ellipses:
        angle = np.deg2rad(angle)
        sa = np.sin(angle)
        ca = np.cos(angle)
        p = np.empty((n, 2))
        p[:, 0] = x0 + a * ca * ct - b * sa * st
        p[:, 1] = y0 + a * sa * ct + b * ca * st
        result.append(p)

    return result

def overlap(ellipse1, ellipse2):
    ea = LinearRing(ellipse1)
    eb = LinearRing(ellipse2)
    mp = ea.intersects(eb)

    if mp == False:
        C = 0

    if mp == True:
        C = 1

    return C
```

[image]

I tried checking if ellipses geometry was not a closed loop but using shapely function is_closed I am getting all True bools.

Comment: Why do you need `mp` and `C`? Just do `return ea.intersects(eb)`.

Comment: Please add a full reproducible example. You're not showing us how you call `ellipse_polyline` or `overlap`.

Comment: C is used for count which is shown on picture bellow, I want to use it a as penalty/constraint for optimization algorithm. ellipse_polyline is called with 2 ellipses [ellipse1, ellipse2] ellipse1 is defined with x, y, a, b, theta. x and y - center of ellipse, a and b are dimensions and theta is rotation angle of ellipse... Overlap is called with the return of function ellipse_polyine - 100 points that make an ellipse.

Comment: It seems like it should be possible to produce a [mcve]. Please do so. (I know it’s been said already, but I thought I’d add the link...)